# How to get the center of this circle

Tags: geometry

I now realize that I have over-simplified the problem in my last post because it is hard to explain in words.

This is the original problem that I am fighting with for more than a week:

[drawing](https://www.desmos.com/geometry/mfwj0suy8k)

There are two lines originating from the origin. The angle of each line in relation to the diagonal is the same and is known. A circle is centered on the diagonal and only a 90 degrees arc of the circle is drawn between the lines. On the arc of the circle is a point P of which the coordinates are known. The dimension and location of the circle is not known, the only thing that is known is that point P lies on the arc and the arc is a 90 degrees segment of a circle with its center on the diagonal.

How can I find the coordinates of the circle?

Comment: One way to do it - equation of the circle is $(x-a)^2 + (y - a)^2 = r^2$. We have two variables $a, r$. Now as $y = x$ also intersects the circle, you have another point on the circle given by $2(x-a)^2 = r^2$. The other given point on the circle will give one more equation (if it is not the same as one we found on the diagonal). Use equation of the lines $y = x \tan \theta$ to get the intersection points and confirm angle subtended on the center is $90^0$.

Comment: What is a? In the drawing it is the angle of the 2 lines that connect the 90 degrees arc of the circle divided by 2. From the answer it seems as if it is part of a coordinate

Comment: $(a,a)$ is coordinate of the center of the circle given it is on line $y = x$.

Answer (score 1):

First, let us identify all the elements:

- The diagonal $d$ is the line $y=x$.
- The point $P$ has coordinates $(p_x,p_y)$.
- The angles are defined by lines $r_A : y=ax$ and $r_B:y=bx$.
- The circle intersects the lines $r_A$ and $r_B$ in points $T : (t_x, t_y)$ and $U : (u_x,u_y)$ respectively (there are two more points of intersection, but you should be able to discard them by inspection).
- You need to find the center $C: (c_x,c_y)$ and the radius $r$ of the circle, which has equation:
  $$(x-c_x)^2 + (y-c_y)^2 = r^2$$

[image: Plot]

Now, here there are several key points that you should try to justify:

- Since the angles to the diagonal are equal, $b=1/a$. Use the angle to deduce the value of a.
- The center lies on the diagonal, so $c_x=c_y$.
- $d$ is the bisector of the angle between lines $r_A$ and $r_B$. Use its properties to conclude that $(t_x,t_y)=(c_x,c_x+r)$ and $(u_x,u_y)=(c_x+r,c_x)$.

Finally, replacing coordinates in the equations of the lines $r_A$, $r_B$ and the circle, you should be able to deduce the values of $c_x$, $c_y$ and $r$ in terms of $a$, $p_x$ and $p_y$.

---

**Detailed steps:**

1. The slope of $r_A$ is given by the tangent of the angel with respect to the horizontal axis:
   $$a=\tan(\frac{\pi}{4} + A),$$
   where $A$ is the angle between $d$ and $r_A$. Analogously, the slope of $r_B$ is
   $$b=\frac{1}{\tan(\frac{\pi}{4} + A)} = \tan(\frac{\pi}{4} - A).$$
2. Since the center $(c_x,c_y)$ lies on $d$ (of equation $y=x$) then it clearly satifies that $c_x=c_y$.
3. The points of $d$ are equidistant from $r_A$ and $r_B$ because $d$ is the angle bisector. Moreover, $\triangle TCU$ needs to be a rectangular and isosceles triangle (with legs of length $r$). So the only way for this to be possible is that $\overline{TC}$ is parallel to the vertical axis (so that $t_x=c_x$) and $\overline{UC}$ is parallel to the horzontal axis (that is, $u_y=c_y=c_x$).
4. Note also that $T$ and $U$ lie on the circle, so the distance to $C$ is $r$. Therefore, $t_y=c_x+r$ and $u_x=c_y+r$.
5. Taking all previous steps into account, knowing that $T$ lies on both $r_A$ an the circle, its coordinates have to satisfy both equations:
   $$\begin{cases}
   c_x + r &= c_x \tan(\frac{\pi}{4} + A),\\
   (p_x-c_x)^2 + (p_y-c_x)^2 &= r^2.
   \end{cases}$$
6. Finally, you need to solve for $r$ in the first equation and replace it in the second one:
   $$(p_x-c_x)^2 + (p_y-c_x)^2 = \left(c_x \tan(\frac{\pi}{4} + A) - c_x\right)^2.$$
   Expand that expression to obtain a quadratic equation on $c_x$ which should be easy to solve (see the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula)) in terms of $p_x$ and $p_y$. The rest of the values can be obtained by replacing $c_x$ with that value.

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive explanation. However, after checking it again and again I have to admit that i am lost in translation... Can you give me an example of how to calculate the center point C for point P(5,6) with angle A and B of 18 degrees?

Comment: Sorry, but that seems a pretty specific question, just like homework. The aim of MSE is to learn, not to get your homework solved. I'm willing to help further, but only if you show some effort. Add whatever you have tried, which step yu found confusing and why... and I'll try to give some more details on that.

Comment: haha, yes I understand. However I am an oldie, it is a long time ago since I did homework (I am 62).

Comment: I started by considering the 2 extreme situations: An angle of 90 degrees (so 2x45) which always has the center of the circle at 0,0 and an angle of 0 degrees which always results in the center of the circle being the same coordinate as P.
I realized that I need the function of the circle and the function of the line O-P and find when they both intersect but that also lead me to nowhere. Then I thought it would be a good idea to take several pieces of paper and make example drawings on them and see if I can find relationships between the circle and the point P

Comment: I have to admit that a lot of my knowledge of geometry went to some forgotten room in my brain (it is some 40 years ago) so I have to dig a lot to get all back again....

Comment: What I also tried was taking the average of P(x) and P(y) and use this value to find the intersection of both lines. This gives a new x and y which is near the center of the circle but not good enough...

Comment: If you are asking for a geometrical construction, I am afraid I do not know any. I only know the analytical one I gave above. I will elaborate on it, but it is basically the one given by @mathcounterexamples.net in their answer.

Comment: @A.vanleyen there you have it.

Comment: I have solved the equation but don't get the right result.
When A=45 degrees the center of the circle is at 0,0 so I get the correct result. But when the angle gets smaller the center of the circles stays at 0,0 so the produced arc is not right.
Is the equation correct?

Answer (score 1):

Reusing the nice picture and notations of [AugSB](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/188245/augsb), you have

$$\begin{cases}
c_x &= (r+c_x)\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4} -A\right)\\
(p_x-c_x)^2 + (p_y-c_x)^2 &= r^2
\end{cases}$$

as $c_x=c_y=u_y$ and where the angle $A$ is given in radians.

Which is equivalent to

$$\begin{cases}
r &=c_x \frac{1 - \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4} -A\right)}{\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4} -A\right)}\\
(p_x-c_x)^2 + (p_y-c_x)^2 &= r^2
\end{cases}$$

$A$ is given. Replacing $r$ from the first equation into the second one you get an equation of the second degree where $c_x$ is the only unknown as $p_x, p_y$ are known. Solving it you get the desired center $C=(c_x,c_x)$.

Comment: I understand that I need to fill in 'r' in the second equation and try to move everything except for the Cx to the other side of the equal sign.
But how to solve this? I have no experience in second degree equations.

Comment: See [Wikipedia second degree equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Quadratic_formula_and_its_derivation).

Comment: @A.vanleyen I provided another answer which is only based on geometry.

Answer (score 1):

A **Straightedge and compass construction**

After algebra, let's come back to geometry. Here is a [Straightedge and compass construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straightedge_and_compass_construction).

The construction comes from following basic idea:

- It is easy to construct an [arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_(geometry)) $A_0$ having all the required properties... except that it isn't passing through $P$.
- From such an arc, the desired arc is the one obtained as the image of previous arc under the [homothetic transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_transformation) $T$.
- The homothety $T$ is the one having for center the origin $O$ and that transforms $P_0$ into $P$.
- Where $P_0$ is the intersection between the arc $A_0$ and the line $(O, P)$.

Base on that, the center $C$ of the desired arc $A$ is the intersection of the line parallel to $(C_0, P_0)$ passing through $P$ with the main diagonal.

**See picture below.**

[image]

[Geogebra file](https://www.geogebra.org/classic/thwjcgxk)